# How to select line in table IE

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

how can i select line in table?
i can do it by xpath, but this method is unsuitable for me because in different data, my line can be in a different order.

example:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='P_ResourceConfigurationGridDFFID_body']/tbody/tr[3]")).click();
```

this table contains several columns
for example:

```
ResourseId | Status

xxxxxxxxx  | active
aaaaaaaaaa | terminated
zzzzzzzzz  | cancelled
```

every resourceid is a link
i need just select line with wanted resourceid but do not click on this resourceid.

Comment: give proper html snippet example or web link to resource

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw4b-Qn0tK26Q1VQaW1XbnhJbUU/view?usp=sharing
Manual Actions:
To select line of table on the screenshot i need to click on empty space near needed element. if i'll click on element i will open new page(i don't need to open it. i need select whole line to do some action with it.)

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to find the line, you can use `By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'your-ResourseId')]")` to find the cell, then use `By.xpath("..")` to get the row.
2. I guess your row binds to 2 functions. The first function is to open the link, another one is to highlight the row. You have to click on the element that bind to the function that highlight row.

Can you post your html? so we can help you to determine which one binds to the function that highlight row.